# converting 2 byte hex numbers back to a decimal

Tags: c, hex, endianness

```
The code below, produces the following output on a serial console
```

`[42][25][f][27][0][0]`.

My question is - if just had the serial output - how would you figure out that the number was 9999? How does the maths work? I think it has something to do with little endian?

```
int a = 9999; 
buf[0] = 'B';
buf[1] = '%';
buf[2] = a&0xff;
buf[3] = (a>>8)&0xff;
buf[4] = (a>>16)&0xff;
buf[5] = (a>>24)&0xff;
```

Comment: This is not about programming, but conversion between number systems, i.e. math/algorithm. And the "code below" does nto generate any output.

Comment: Code converts `a` into 4 bytes.  Why do you want a 2 byte hex to decimal conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Endianness determines how numbers are stored in memory, not how arithmetic is performed on it. Since the C code you provided only uses integer arithmetic (i.e. does not deal with pointers and memory access), the resulting data will be the same whatever the endianness is.

To serialize your number, you extract every byte (`&0xff`) of your number by applying bit shifting (respectively 0, 8, 16 and 24 bits); e.g. `0xAABBCCDD >> 8` becomes `0xAABBCC`, and the binary AND operation `&0xff` discards the upper bytes to keep the least significant one, in case of the example it is `0xCC`.

To undo that operation, you have to take the bytes and AND them together, applying bit shifts in the opposite direction. Parsing `i` would use the following code:

```
int a = buf[2] & (buf[3] << 8) & (buf[4] << 16) & (buf[5] << 24);
```

There is no need to cast any of the operands here as using bitwise operators in C implies integer promotion (ISO/IEC 9899§6.3.1.1), and your resulting variable type is `int` — that is, assuming `buf` is an array of an `unsigned` 8-bit integer type.

Note this assumes the emitter of the serialized data also has a 32-bit `int` length, and uses the same signed number representation (often [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

Comment: "There is no need to cast any of the operands here as using bitwise operators in C implies integer promotion" That's exactly why you _should_ cast the operands. Bit shifts on signed types can easily invoke undefined behavior. For example `buf[5] << 24` always invokes undefined behavior if `buf[5]` happened to hold a value larger than 0x7F.

Comment: @Lundin Bitwise operators have no relation to signedness when it comes to *output*; `6.5.7` describes the behaviour of both bit-shift operators and only distinguishes the signedness of the 1st operand. Assuming an `unsigned`, 8-bit type for `buf` elements makes it safe (they won't go past `0xFF`, so the `<< 24` shift is always representable since 32-bit integers are assumed) — I edited the answer to reflect that. `&`-ing the results together is also safe as the  operator, as per `6.5.10`, only do bitwise AND regardless of the input data.

Comment: Implicit type promotion. If the operand is a small integer type of any signedness, it will end up as `int` which is signed. Assuming unsigned 8bit type before implicit promotion, you get undefined behavior if large enough to left shift data into the sign bits of the promoted signed type. If it is `int`, also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

knowing how data are embedded into message, you can extrapolate them converting in the right format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int32_t a = 9999;
    unsigned char buf[6];
    buf[0] = 'B';
    buf[1] = '%';
    buf[2] = a&0xff;
    buf[3] = (a>>8)&0xff;
    buf[4] = (a>>16)&0xff;
    buf[5] = (a>>24)&0xff;

    uint32_t res= buf[2] + ((buf[3] & 0xFFFFFFFFu) << 8) + ((buf[4] & 0xFFFFFFFFu) << 16) + ((buf[5] & 0xFFFFFFFFu) << 24);

    printf("Converted from chars: %d\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

As data are pushed into buffer, you can position they back at the correct location in an int variable.

> I think it has something to do with little endian?

Endianness doesn't matter because shift operations are made on the host platform considering its architecture.

Comment: NMDV yet `& 0xFFFFFFFFu` looks strange even though it is functionally correct aside from converting `unsigned` to `int` may invoke `int` overflow and initial `(int)` serves no purpose.  Also, OP did ask for "**2** byte hex numbers back to a decimal".  IDK, guess you have a [tough crowd](http://ct.fra.bz/ol/fz/sw/i52/5/5/9/frabz-Tough-crowd-no-respect-dbff09.jpg) today.

Comment: @chux ahah. It was a joke, I'm afraid I know how downvoted ;) BTW OP asked for 2 byte but the code uses 4 bytes to store the int. About the overflow I was sure due to the source of number `int a`. am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure.  I'll ponder it.  (review 1's sign/mag implications)

Comment: @chux Not getting you. using unsigned 32bit hex literal how can shift overflow on signed, so ub?

Comment: Assigned a 32-bit unsigned value to an `int` is the potential UB, not the shifting part.

Comment: @chux oooh I see. Got it. Tx

Answer (score 0):

The hexi decimal number system is a base 16 numeral system. 
This means that it consists of 16 different symbols and has The weight of 16.

What this means is that instead of only having 10 symbols(0-9)for illustrating numbers as in the decimal (base 10 ) system, you have 16 0-f.
  Where the symbols a=10,b=11,c=12,d=13,e=14 and f=15 in The decimal system.

The weight part of the system means that the frist symbol in a hex digit has the weight of 1 which is also the case in the decimal system. 
  But if the number is represented by more than one digit, that weight is increased by 16.

So in hex:

- f = 16^0*15 in decimal.
- ff = (16^1*15)+15 in decimal.
- fff=(16^2*15)+(16^1*15)+15 in decimal
- n...fff = ((16^n-1)*m)+...+(16^2*15)+(16^1*15)+15 in decimal where m represents a given hex symbol.

This number system is widely used in electrical Engineering and hardware near software development, because it allows one to group bits in groups of fours and thereby illustrate large binary numbers more compact.